# Does malloc() have a maximum return value?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

Does the `size_t` value of the virtual memory pointer returned by `malloc()` have an upper boundary?

I am wondering whether I can safely set the most significant bit of a 64 bits pointer to indicate that this is not a pointer but a literal integer instead.

Comment: what's wrong with `int64_t` or `uint64_t`?

Comment: It depends on the `OS`' memory mapping strategy and because the strategy is an implementation details it can change from one version of the `OS` to the next one without any warning. I would not rely on such hacks.

Comment: Something in your question is rather unclear (at least to me). Suppose you called `malloc` and it returned the address of a newly allocated memory block. How could changing the MSB of that value make it "indicate a literal string". I suppose that what you mean is - "are there any values that are never returned by `malloc`, which I can safely use in order to distinguish them from values that **are** returned by `malloc`?". That said, if you provide the relevant piece of your code (namely, the function that returns the pointer), someone here might suggest a clean safe way to achieve your goal.

Comment: You can do this safely, but not "in C": you'll need to completely forget about C's abstract semantics and read up on the pointer rules for your *hardware* platform (you can write the code in C if you like, but that's a detail). [Can be done on x64](https://wingolog.org/archives/2011/05/18/value-representation-in-javascript-implementations).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @datenwolf's answer states, you can't make any assumptions about how `malloc` is providing you the memory address. The MSB may well contain important bits that you could overwrite, if you attempted to use them to store meta data. I have worked on a 32-bit system that returned addresses with bits set in the MSB of addresses (not from `malloc`, but other system specific memory allocation functions).

However, it *is* guaranteed that `malloc` will return an address that is suitably aligned for your system. For example, on a 32-bit system, you'll get a 4-byte aligned pointer, and on 64-bit, you'll get an 8-byte aligned pointer. This means that you are guaranteed that the lower 2 or 3 bits respectively *will* be zero. You could increase the number of guaranteed bits by using `memalign` instead. It essentially is the same effect as storing meta data in the most significant bit. To get/set the literal, you can just up/down shift it into the remaining bits.

However, I wouldn't suggest either method. Save yourself some heartache, and allocate just a little more memory to store the flag. Unless you've got billions of them, it's really not worth it.

Comment: Good one, that would do the trick. Indeed, I've got billions of them and I've already solved the problem, but I was curious to know more about `malloc()`.

Answer (score 8):

malloc returns a `void*` not an integer. Casting a pointer to an integer is not giving you the (virtual memory) address, but some value that has to adhere to the semantics as defined in the C language standard (0 for a null pointer and adding and subtracting is related to pointer arithmetic), but that's about it.

You must make no assumptions whatsoever about the values of pointers-cast-to-integers other than that. As a matter of fact a C implementation may very well be in its right to tag non-null pointer cast to integer with some internal information in the upper bits.

Answer (score 0):

As for the `size_t` is concerned it can hold a value defined by limits.h

```
#ifndef SIZE_MAX
#ifdef _WIN64 
#define SIZE_MAX _UI64_MAX
#else
#define SIZE_MAX UINT_MAX
```

Where _UI64_MAX and UINT_MAX are defined as followes.

```
#define UINT_MAX      0xffffffff    /* maximum unsigned int value */
#define _UI64_MAX     0xffffffffffffffffui64
```

And as for the `malloc()` is concerned, on a 32 bit Windows it can return any (address) value within zero to 2 GB user-mode address space and on a 64 bit Windows it can return any (address) value within zero to 8 TB user-mode address space.

Again, on a 32 bit system, from WinNT 4 onwards it introduced a boot option /3G. With this, `malloc()` can return any (address) value within zero to 3 GB user-mode address space.

For more details have a look at Mark Russinovich's article [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx).